# How do I resolve import with absolute path?

Tags: npm, brunch

What do I need to setup in brunch-config.js to be able to resolve absolute path from project's root folder? i.e

```
import { helper } from '/imports/utilities/helper'
```

The reason being is I have a legacy React app and it imports local files by using relative path. While I'm trying to use brunch, I need to figure out a way to setup brunch so that it understands the path without having to change the code.

I tried to use npm alias but not sure how it works

```
npm: {
  aliases: {
    '/imports': 'imports/**'
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be an OK question, but you might want to add some details about why you're trying to accomplish this, or things you have tried. People here tend to be leery of short questions.

Comment: @Haem updated. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution with [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver) package.

Since all my codes are under `/imports` dir, in `brunch-config.js` I setup an alias based on their [documentation](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/blob/HEAD/DOCS.md#alias):

```
plugins: {
  babel: {
    plugins: [
      ...,
      ["module-resolver", {
        "root": ["./imports"],
        "alias": {
          "/imports": ([, path]) => `./imports${path}`,
        }
      }]
    ],
    presets: [
      ...
    ],
  }
},
```

That way, if I do `import Screen from '/imports/components/screens'` it will resolve the file under `./imports/components/screens`

You can set the alias in `.babelrc` too but you might want to use regex instead.